# Convert 'connections.json' file to 'tnsnames.ora'

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to convert 'connections.json' file to 'tnsnames.ora'?
Well i have approx 50 database connections and i plan not to write them up 1 by 1 in a notepad or something. Is there a much simpler way?

Im using Sqldeveloper Version: 20.2.0.175.1842

Below is the quarter of my "connections.json" file. The file is very huge.

```
{
    "connections": [{
                "info": {
                    "role": "",
                    "SavePassword": "true",
                    "OracleConnectionType": "BASIC",
                    "RaptorConnectionType": "Oracle",
                    "serviceName": "ABC",
                    "Connection-Color-For-Editors": "-12417793",
                    "customUrl": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//a.b.c.d:1526/BDNPDBP",
                    "oraDriverType": "thin",
                    "NoPasswordConnection": "TRUE",
                    "password": "aaa/bbb/ccc=",
                    "hostname": "a.b.c.d",
                    "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
                    "port": "1526",
                    "subtype": "oraJDBC",
                    "OS_AUTHENTICATION": "false",
                    "ConnName": "BDAPDPBP-SGP-PRD_FAB",
                    "KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION": "false",
                    "user": "ABC"
                },
                "name": "BDAPDPBP-SGP-PRD_FAB",
                "type": "jdbc"
            }, ...
```

Comment: Can u please be share how your connection.json looks like?

Comment: It depends on your type of connection, if you're using tns connection types, then probably not. If you're using basic connections, then probably yes.

Comment: @roshaga , Ive copied the connection.json file that i have see above...

Comment: careful what you share @roshaga - i updated your question to hide sensitive info in your connections file

Comment: thanks @thatjeffsmith infact ive giberished/changed alots of data before copy over to this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following PowerShell function to aid the conversion of the `connections.json` to `tnsnames.ora` file:

[[image: GitHub Logo] GitHub Gist for `ConvertTo-TnsnamesOra`](https://gist.github.com/mavaddat/cf61a8d79ae83645095b260a998d9361)

The work is done by this one-liner:

```powershell
Get-Content -Path "$env:APPDATA\SQL Developer\system*\o.jdeveloper.db.connection\connections.json" | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty connections | ForEach-Object {
        $serviceName = $_.info.serviceName
        $hostName = $_.info.hostname
        $port = $_.info.port
        @"
$serviceName=
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $hostName)(PORT = $port))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVICE_NAME = $serviceName)
        )
    )
"@
    } | Write-Output
```

[image: Screenshot recording of using the function]

Example input `connections.json`, randomly generated:

```json
{
  "connections": [
    {
      "info": {
        "role": "",
        "SavePassword": "true",
        "OracleConnectionType": "BASIC",
        "PROXY_TYPE": "USER NAME",
        "RaptorConnectionType": "Oracle",
        "serviceName": "BLUEBONNET",
        "customUrl": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//multiply7-strongly.ca.heartily.solstice.net:24306/BLUEBONNET",
        "oraDriverType": "thin",
        "NoPasswordConnection": "TRUE",
        "hostname": "multiply7-strongly.ca.heartily.solstice.net",
        "password": "ahz/JFNgoT/4vikL4qPIxpJ0pl8NmK2gNCxc4AxD4R8Q",
        "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
        "subtype": "oraJDBC",
        "port": "24306",
        "OS_AUTHENTICATION": "False",
        "IS_PROXY": "False",
        "KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION": "False)",
        "user": "KNOCKER)",
        "PROXY_USER_NAME": ""
      },
      "name": "bluebonnet",
      "type": "jdbc"
    },
    {
      "info": {
        "role": "",
        "SavePassword": "true",
        "OracleConnectionType": "BASIC",
        "PROXY_TYPE": "USER NAME",
        "RaptorConnectionType": "Oracle",
        "serviceName": "BLAST",
        "customUrl": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//happy8-tom.ca.shopkeeper.unveil.gov:24638/BLAST",
        "oraDriverType": "thin",
        "NoPasswordConnection": "FALSE",
        "hostname": "happy8-tom.ca.shopkeeper.unveil.gov",
        "password": "GnjgFBJtrj4+TNCnD4Cm6vVyl2EJV4rQUsDVgdhiVOWq",
        "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
        "subtype": "oraJDBC",
        "port": "24638",
        "OS_AUTHENTICATION": "True",
        "IS_PROXY": "True",
        "KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION": "True)",
        "user": "PEDANTIC)",
        "PROXY_USER_NAME": ""
      },
      "name": "blast",
      "type": "jdbc"
    },
    {
      "info": {
        "role": "",
        "SavePassword": "true",
        "OracleConnectionType": "BASIC",
        "PROXY_TYPE": "USER NAME",
        "RaptorConnectionType": "Oracle",
        "serviceName": "SALVO",
        "customUrl": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//stalk7-invader.ca.superimpose.drive.ca:13901/SALVO",
        "oraDriverType": "thin",
        "NoPasswordConnection": "TRUE",
        "hostname": "stalk7-invader.ca.superimpose.drive.ca",
        "password": "yADC4BiCXJDwTxjqV2VnR/TaLxgwKuVIeC6Qb2XKeWSL",
        "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
        "subtype": "oraJDBC",
        "port": "13901",
        "OS_AUTHENTICATION": "False",
        "IS_PROXY": "False",
        "KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION": "True)",
        "user": "CHEWY)",
        "PROXY_USER_NAME": ""
      },
      "name": "salvo",
      "type": "jdbc"
    },
    {
      "info": {
        "role": "",
        "SavePassword": "true",
        "OracleConnectionType": "BASIC",
        "PROXY_TYPE": "USER NAME",
        "RaptorConnectionType": "Oracle",
        "serviceName": "RETRAIN",
        "customUrl": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//leukemia3-plantar.ca.coinsurance.grooming.co:17210/RETRAIN",
        "oraDriverType": "thin",
        "NoPasswordConnection": "TRUE",
        "hostname": "leukemia3-plantar.ca.coinsurance.grooming.co",
        "password": "QkAtCgVAuq8ie8rzWrnV1pURN612i1TBciTxSk0tehA8",
        "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
        "subtype": "oraJDBC",
        "port": "17210",
        "OS_AUTHENTICATION": "False",
        "IS_PROXY": "False",
        "KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION": "False)",
        "user": "LEFTY)",
        "PROXY_USER_NAME": ""
      },
      "name": "retrain",
      "type": "jdbc"
    },
    {
      "info": {
        "role": "",
        "SavePassword": "true",
        "OracleConnectionType": "BASIC",
        "PROXY_TYPE": "USER NAME",
        "RaptorConnectionType": "Oracle",
        "serviceName": "STOKE",
        "customUrl": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//evaporate8-garlicky.ca.prudishly.mammon.dev:21323/STOKE",
        "oraDriverType": "thin",
        "NoPasswordConnection": "TRUE",
        "hostname": "evaporate8-garlicky.ca.prudishly.mammon.dev",
        "password": "JieYvzB6aZvDWrXjuAAT/r0qCDRoBVHcpSTWHPEKFhnV",
        "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
        "subtype": "oraJDBC",
        "port": "21323",
        "OS_AUTHENTICATION": "True",
        "IS_PROXY": "True",
        "KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION": "False)",
        "user": "SCRAPPER)",
        "PROXY_USER_NAME": ""
      },
      "name": "stoke",
      "type": "jdbc"
    },
    {
      "info": {
        "role": "",
        "SavePassword": "true",
        "OracleConnectionType": "BASIC",
        "PROXY_TYPE": "USER NAME",
        "RaptorConnectionType": "Oracle",
        "serviceName": "GRAINY",
        "customUrl": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//syncope1-mendelevium.ca.mold.diagram.com:7535/GRAINY",
        "oraDriverType": "thin",
        "NoPasswordConnection": "FALSE",
        "hostname": "syncope1-mendelevium.ca.mold.diagram.com",
        "password": "YxhVToLSNUVzs68RSTqgD/LyES42AlpQnxwFTnHMbgd8",
        "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
        "subtype": "oraJDBC",
        "port": "7535",
        "OS_AUTHENTICATION": "False",
        "IS_PROXY": "True",
        "KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION": "False)",
        "user": "GLORY)",
        "PROXY_USER_NAME": ""
      },
      "name": "grainy",
      "type": "jdbc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result, `tnsnames.ora`:

```
BLUEBONNET=
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = multiply7-strongly.ca.heartily.solstice.net)(PORT = 24306))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVICE_NAME = BLUEBONNET)
        )
    )
BLAST=
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = happy8-tom.ca.shopkeeper.unveil.gov)(PORT = 24638))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVICE_NAME = BLAST)
        )
    )
SALVO=
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = stalk7-invader.ca.superimpose.drive.ca)(PORT = 13901))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVICE_NAME = SALVO)
        )
    )
RETRAIN=
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = leukemia3-plantar.ca.coinsurance.grooming.co)(PORT = 17210))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVICE_NAME = RETRAIN)
        )
    )
STOKE=
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = evaporate8-garlicky.ca.prudishly.mammon.dev)(PORT = 21323))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVICE_NAME = STOKE)
        )
    )
GRAINY=
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = syncope1-mendelevium.ca.mold.diagram.com)(PORT = 7535))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVICE_NAME = GRAINY)
        )
    )
```

Validate using http://brantwills.github.io/tns-check/ by [@Brant-Wills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1263168/brant-wills)

[image]